# Position Widget in the center and add some text to the right

Tags: flutter

I’m trying to make a progress bar and I'd like to place the progress bar in the middle and a text next to it, but I don't know how

I don't want both elements centralized just the progress bar

The result I get:

[image: The result I get]

The result I'm expecting:

[image: The result I'm expecting]

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProgressBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text("Progress Bar"),
        Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            width: 95,
            height: 6,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
              width: 47.5,
            ),
          ),
          Text('50 %'),
        ]),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I tried with your code:

```
Column(
  children: [
    Row(children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Center(
          child: Text("Progress Bar"),
        ),
        flex: 2,
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Container(),
      ),
    ]),
    Row(children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.grey, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          width: 95,
          height: 6,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
            width: 47.5,
          ),
        ),
        flex: 2,
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Center(
          child: Text('50 %'),
        ),
      ),
    ]),
  ],
);
```

Giving the following layout:

[image: Layout]

I'm guessing this is what you wanted to achieve. Have a look at how I've used `Expanded` to balance the constraints in each row. The basic logic is to have the Progress Bar text and the Progress bar in the same column and give this column the same width, hence the use of Expanded with the same flex. Since you wanted the 50% in the same row as the Progress bar, I then added an empty 'cell' above it to keep the placement intact. It's basically like creating a table using `Column` and `Row`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need your `Progress Bar` text and your actual `Bar` to be aligned, you would need to wrap them inside a `Column`.

Then, you can wrap this and your `Text` in a `Row`.

```
class ProgressBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FittedBox(child: Row(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
          child: FittedBox(
            child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, children: [
              Text("Progress Bar"),
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                width: 95,
                height: 6,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
                  width: 47.5,
                ),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ),
        Text('50 %'),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Here, we are using a `Padding` to make the `Text` widget go a bit towards the bottom. The `FittedBox`s are there to avoid your `Column` and `Row` from taking all available space.

Result

[image]